# iPhone - detailView controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, detailsview

I am having a tableView which lists the contents directory which includes jpg, pdf, zip, mp3, mp4, sql,.. files and even folders. In the next step, I am having a detailView which displays some properties of the selected file such as fileName, fileSize, filePath, fileType. Everything works perfect.

But actually my plan is to include a additional option in the detailView.

That is,

1. If the selected file in the tableView is a image file, it should open a imageView in the detailView to display that image.
2. If the selected file is a mp3, it should open a player to play the song in the detailView.
3. If the selected file is a video or mp4 file, it should open a player to play that video in detailView.
4. If the selected item is a folder, it should again open a tableView which dispalys the contents of the folder.
5. For other files, it should push a alertView regarding that it is a unknown file.

Hope my concept was narrated well. I got the methods for playing the .mp3 and .mp4 files. Now I am stuck in pushing the imageView and in case of a folder. I have no ideas to proceed both the methods.

This is my tableView
[image]

This is my detailView for video file
[image]

This is my detailView for a .mp3 file
[image]

This is the detailView left empty for my imageView.
[image]

Please help me to proceed with some sample codes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry. I cant able to upload my screenshots in the last few steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your screenshots and progress of implementing the other filetypes, I assume you are able to pass the information of the file path to the detail view.  So, for the image file, I am going to discuss how to display it into a `UIImageView`.

For the image view, You will want create a `UIImage` with the path.

Code example below: Assume that `pathString` is an `NSString*` with the image path, and that `imageView` is now a `UIImageView` which should display the image.  This code would reside in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the `detailViewController` handling the image display.

```
UIImage* theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentOfFile:pathString];
imageView.image = theImage;
[theImage release];
```

As for the folder view, this is a bit different.  For the best result you will want to recursively load the `tableViewController` you are using to display the list of files now (so that it will inherit all the file/folder handling recursively).

I would suggest to add an instance variable like `folderPath` to the `tableViewController` that you set before actually pushing the view.  And the `tableViewController` should use this as the base path.

Code example below: Assume that `pathString` is an `NSString*` with the destination path, and that `detailViewController` is now an instance of the new `tableViewController` to be opened.  This code would reside in the method that will create the new `detailViewController` to be displayed, somewhere within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
detailViewController.folderPath = pathString;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

You should then implement in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the `tableViewController`, on what folder content should be read from the `folderPath` instance variable.

Comment: Thank you. The methods for imageView works. But I am stuck in folder part. I have no ideas how to push a tableView for a tableView recursively. Can you help me with a source code or any tutorial?

Comment: What I mean by recursively, is that the TableViewController that you use to view the files, will load another instance of itself to display the contents of the subfolder.  Your TableViewController should have a property that defines which path it is displaying, so that each subfolder item will pass it's full path to the new TableViewController to load.



Let me know if you need some further explanation/code.

Answer (score 0):

This method **`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`**
is called when there is touch occurred on some cell.

You can get cell with **`[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndex];`**

After that you can see type property, and open appropriate viewcontroller.
**`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];`**

Comment: Huh. I dont have any idea how to use an imageView in the detailView and use it to display the selected image. Can I get any guidance regarding that?

Comment: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theimagefile" ofType:@"png"]];
 
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

Answer (score 0):

When you create your detailView, you should overload the init with additional parameters that indicate the type of media to display and the url/file of this resource.

If it's for an image, [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680109/uiimage-and-uiimageview-problem)